# How to get current locale with i18next / react-i18next?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-i18next

I'm new to react-native and I'm trying to get current locale from the device of the user. For now, I have 2 versions of my app : french and english. It works fine when I change the fallback language I do have the two versions of the app. But I can't manage to change the language directly from the device.

We can change manually, but if we have set french language on device then we can't get french language directly.

[image]

```
import i18next from 'i18next';
import {initReactI18next} from 'react-i18next';

const languageDetector = {
  type: 'languageDetector',
  async: true,
  detect: cb => cb('en'),
  init: () => {},
  cacheUserLanguage: () => {},
};

i18next
  .use(languageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: true,
    resources: {
      en: {
        translation: {
          hello: 'Hello world',
          change: 'Change language',
        },
      },
      sv: {
        translation: {
          hello: 'Hallo!',
          change: 'Goedemorgen',
        },
      },
    },
  });

export default i18next;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import './src/Traslations'


export default function App() {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, marginBottom: 20 }}>{t('hello')}</Text>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, marginBottom: 20 }}>{t('change')}</Text>

      <TouchableOpacity style={{backgroundColor: 'pink'}} onPress={() => i18n.changeLanguage(i18n.language === 'nl' ? 'en' : 'nl')}>
        <Text>{t('change')}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
  }
```

Comment: You want your app to detect changes in `device-lang` ... and refresh `app-lang` automatically ... is that what you mean?

Comment: Can you please review above gif image? I hope you will get idea from that.

Comment: Could you please include the code in your `I18n/index.js`

Comment: I didn't got your point, I've already include code of both language

Comment: Your `i18n` code where you detect lang-changes and set your `fallback` lang...

Comment: Check above code.

Answer (score 1):

[i18next.resolvedLanguage](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#resolvedlanguage) or [i18next.language](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#language) or [i18next.languages](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#languages) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `languageDetector` uses `en` as a `fallback` lang...

**Make Sure** that the *language-prefix* you choose in your device is `sv` <<-- the key you're having in your `i18n` setup...

```
const languageDetector = {
  type: 'languageDetector',
  async: true,
  detect: cb => cb('en'), // <<---- here
  init: () => {},
  cacheUserLanguage: () => {},
};
```

**Instead**

You'd want to pass current-device-lang

```
import { Platform, NativeModules, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
const getDeviceLang = () => {
  const appLanguage =
    Platform.OS === 'ios'
      ? NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLocale ||
        NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLanguages[0]
      : NativeModules.I18nManager.localeIdentifier;

  return appLanguage.search(/-|_/g) !== -1
    ? appLanguage.slice(0, 2)
    : appLanguage;
};

detect: async callback => {
  const deviceLang = getDeviceLang();
  callback(appLanguage);
},
```

**More details could be found [here](https://hend-elsahli-freelance.medium.com/how-to-dynamically-change-app-language-and-app-direction-in-react-native-bfccf567c40c) with a working sample...**

Comment: Your solution is best, but actually I'm finding without fetch default language. It seems it should be support also in library also.. Anyway. Thank you for your answered.